# When calendar is focused and blurred, the date is read multiple times by NVDA screen reader in FF

Tags: jquery, datepicker, nvda

Hi I am trying to provide accessibility to `jquery datepicker`.

The `NVDA` is reading date when i navigate to other dates.

My problem is when initially `datepicker` is opened, the focused date is read 4-10 times. And when `datepicker` is closed the date is read 4-10 times

HTML:

```
<p>Date:
<input id="datepicker" type="text">
    <button id="add_30">Add 30 days </button>
    <button id="add_60">Add 60 days </button>
    <button id="add_90">Add 90 days </button>
</p>

<div id="liveRegion" aria-live="assertive"></div>
```

JS:

```
var message;
 function emitChanges(){                
//Emit message
    message = ' ' + $('.ui-state-hover').html() + ' ' + $('.ui-datepicker-month').html() + ' ' + $('.ui-datepicker-year').html();
    document.getElementById('liveRegion').innerHTML = message;
  }

//Check for changes to DOM 
var target = document.querySelector('#ui-datepicker-div');

if(!document.attachEvent) {
    //Using not attachEvent to filter out IE 8 & 9.
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations){
      emitChanges();
    });
    var config = { attributes: true, characterData: true };
    observer.observe(target, config);
  } else {
    //Using event attach for IE8
    target.attachEvent("onpropertychange", emitChanges);
  }
```

How do I fix this issue. Can I use any role or aria attribute to stop this from reading multiple times.

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/archanabr05/D4AGz/719/